# double integrals and iterated integrals

Tags: analysis

Give an example (if any) for a non-integrable function $f:\mathbb{R\times R}$ $\to$ 
$\mathbb{R}$ with domain in $[0,1]^2$ such that both iterated integrals exists(i.e. in both order of integration).
Here is what I have got:
$$
f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
e^{-xy}\sin x \sin y, & \text{if }x,y \geq 0 \\
0, & \text{otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$
 Does this function work for my case? I found this in :http://www.mathnet.or.kr/mathnet/kms_tex/80630.pdf. It says that iterated integrals exist but not double integrals. I am not sure if this implies Riemann integral does not exist.

Comment: The example shows that $f$ is not integrable over $[0,\infty)^2$; the function is continuous on $[0,1]^2$ hence definitely integrable there. (I won't post this as an answer because I have no time to find answers to the rest of the question.)

Comment: so, just to be sure again, you mean f satisfies both the requirements, right?

Comment: Yes, both the iterated integrals exist on $[0,1]^2$, but so does the double (= Riemann) integral.

Comment: I am sorry, you confused me: you say double(=Riemann) exists :)

Comment: The Riemann integral over $[0,1]^2$ exists. The Riemann integral over $[0,\infty)^2$ does not. So $f$ does not provide an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the function

$$ f(x,y)= \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}. $$

Now, if you evaluate the integral

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)dydx = \frac{\pi}{4},$$

and if you consider the other order, you get

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)dxdy = -\frac{\pi}{4}. $$

So, the iterated integrals exist, but the double integral does not.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying.

Comment: @user77440: You are very welcome.

Comment: Perhaps what's wanted is a *bounded* function?